# Raggedleft in tabular with dotfill

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, dotfill

I would like to make a tabular with three columns, the first two should be raggedright and the last one should be raggedleft. The lines should be filled with dotfill.

Here my (hopefully working) minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{@{}p{3cm}<{\dotfill}@{}p{2cm}<{\dotfill}@{}p{\dimexpr\linewidth-5cm}<{\dotfill}@{}}
    column1a & column2a & column3a \\
    column1b & column2b & column3b 
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `>` not `<` for the last column

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{@{}p{3cm}<{\dotfill}@{}p{2cm}<{\dotfill}@{}>{\dotfill}p{\dimexpr\linewidth-5cm}@{}}
    column1a & column2a & column3a \\
    column1b & column2b & column3b 
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Oh. Thanks...:)